# How to let Django fill an html template, then let the user download it without showing it in browser?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have an HTML template, and I want django to fill it with some data, but rather than redirect the user to a view that uses this template, I want Django to send the filled-template to the user as a download file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: *Any suggestions?* - Using Google?

Comment: Aside from not trying anything... why? I had hoped 2016 would continue to  help rid the world of files..

Comment: I'm developing a tool that performs some functions, and I need the result as html output, but I need to have it opened somewhere else not on the page where the user uses the service, of course I'll let users download this along with other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a regular view, but before returning the response, you set the HTTP Header `Content-Disposition`.

```
def download_form(request):
    form = ...
    response = render(request, 'form_template.html', {'form': form})
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="form.html"'
    return response
```